# Extracting japanese characters from pdf file using itext

Tags: pdf, text, itext, extract

I am trying to extract text from a pdf file that has japanese characters. I am using iText for this purpose
However I am getting this exception.

Exception in thread "main" ExceptionConverter: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Font 'KozMinPro-Regular' with 'UniJIS-UCS2-H' is not recognized.

Can anybody help me with resolving this issue.

Comment: Are you using iTextAsian.jar?
What version of iText are you running?
Can you read the original PDF in Acrobat Reader?